# UIView setFrame jittery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7

I have a header `UIView` in my `UIViewController` for which I perform the `setFrame` function when my `UITableView` scrolls. This is basically for the same effect as the headers on the Facebook and Instagram apps have. But when I do this continuous change, the header does not move smoothly, there is sometimes a lag and the movement hence seems jittery. Is there a way to avoid this jitter?

Comment: You can take a look at [ninjinkun/NJKScrollFullScreen](https://github.com/ninjinkun/NJKScrollFullScreen) and [luugiathuy/GTScrollNavigationBar](https://github.com/luugiathuy/GTScrollNavigationBar) for inspiration.

Comment: Why not make it a sibling of the table view so that its frame doesn't have to change a the time?

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis - Thanks! I'll check them out.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist. I considered that. But then the kind of extra effects such as fading out of header title and buttons would become quite complicated.